# Assign one text box to second text box with key press event on both text box using jquery?

Tags: jquery

i have a 2 text box box.now i want to one text on key press event value enter this value automatically write in the second text box with key press event.so now i want to key press event also got second text box.so how can do that i don't know.

here is my text box :

```
<input type="search" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
```

this is my script code :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#search").keypress(function () {
        debugger;
        //$("#anotherName").val($(this).val());           
            $(".fixed-table-container").find(".dataTables_filter input.input-sm[type='search']").val($(this).val()); // want to also this text box key press event    // this is my 2nd text box       
    });
})
</script>
```

so here write now first text box key press event is working so now i want to same time 2nd text box key press want.

for example i am write abc on 1st textbox that same time keypress using abc write automatically in 2nd textbox but that time i want keypress event also for 2nd textbox.

Comment: You mean you want to also trigger the keypress event on the second textbox when it is triggered on the first?

Comment: yes @AndrewMairose i want like this

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search1').keyup(function() {
    $('#search2').val($(this).val());
  });
  $('#search2').keyup(function() {
    $('#search1').val($(this).val());
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search1">
<input type="text" id="search2">
```

Comment: no for ex i m write abc on 1st text box then key press i m create and abc value is write in 2nd text box but i want to 2nd text box key press event also

Comment: sorry, don't get it. What do you mean by 'another keypress event'?

Answer (score 0):

How about like this, using a class - type in either to replicate in both:

```js
$('.text__input').on('input', function() {
  $('.text__input').val($(this).val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="text__input">
<input type="text" class="text__input">
```

Comment: like this working well in my code but i want to 2nd textbox keypress event

Comment: I don't know what you mean - keypress to do what in 2nd text box?

Answer (score 0):

To trigger an event on an element, use jQuery's [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function.

In your case, to trigger the `keypress` event on the second textbox when `keypress` is triggered on your first textbox, try something like this:

```
$('#textbox1').keypress(function() {
    $('#textbox2').val($(this).val());
    $('#textbox2').trigger('keypress');
});
```

Comment: but $('#textbox2') here value is default set or not i m enter on 1 text box

Comment: mean i m enter abc on 1 text box then  in 2 nd text box set this abc value or not??with your help code

Comment: You could still set the value first. Updated the answer to show this. Is that what you mean?

Comment: actually my second text box is inbulit search text box in datatable angularjs so i don't know this search box is which event is work.do you know?please let me know

Comment: Oh boy, sounds like you've got a case of trying to mix jQuery and angular too much. You don't want to be setting values with jQuery if you're using angular. You'd want to use angular binding to bind your inputs to variables in your controller (assuming you're using angular 1.x), then just set the values in your controller. Read up more on angular two-way binding.

Comment: Check out [`ngBind`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind)
 and [`ngKeypress`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress#!) or [`ngChange`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
    /* if I write in both text boxes*/
    $('#tboxBalance').on('keypress', function () {
        $('#tboxResultado').on('keypress', function () {
            $('#btn_info_gUnidades').prop('disabled', false)
        })
    });
```